# Is there a name for a real-valued function whose input is also real?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology, definition, real-numbers

I'm trying to write a sentence about a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and I want to refer to it as real valued or as a scalar function, or some similar term, but I want that term to also indicate that the function has real domain, as well as range.

Is there a special name for functions from the reals to the reals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is a function from a subset of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$, we call it a real function of one real variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$